# Is there an easy way to implement an exchange mail server?

Tags: exchange-server, activesync

I am a total newbie in exchange. My company has email service which support imap and pop3, but  the boss want to implement an exchange protocol, I read some articles said that exchange(ActiveSync) is not an open protocol, is there a way to easily learn it and implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from buying Exchange Server, you could look at building an Exchange ActiveSync implementation yourself (using the [documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc425499%28v=EXCHG.80%29.aspx) as a starting point), or use a 3rd-party implementation like [Z-Push](http://z-push.sourceforge.net/soswp/) (which is open-source and free).

Comment: You'll still have to license the ActiveSync protocol from Microsoft. It's an open protocol only in terms of its details being publicly documented, and building a client or server that speaks it requires a license from them.

Comment: AFAIK, Microsoft recently switched to making the protocol free to implement (both server and client), but charges for certifying *clients* against the spec.